# typeerror: null is not an object (evaluating '_blemodule.blemodule.createclient')

Tags: react-native

followed the steps to install react-native-ble-plx module for android

1. npm install --save react-native-ble-plx
2. checked in buid.gradle file **minSdkVersion = 21** which id already available
3. **maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }** added in build.gradle file
4. lastly added in AndroidManifest.xml according to documentation

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { BleManager } from 'react-native-ble-plx';

const App = () => {
    const manager = new BleManager();
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(manager)
    })
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>hii</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "white",
    },
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: typeerror: null is not an object (evaluating '_blemodule.blemodule.createclient') ,i am getting this error when i used * const manager = new BleManager(); * this line which is giving me the error . even after following all the steps given in documentation

Comment: this library is used in my project for android development and the link is https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx